# Wrong example in composition series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

According to the Abstract Algebra, Theory and Applications by Thomas W. Judson:

> $\quad$ A subnormal series $\{H_i\}$ of a group $G$ is a ***composition series*** if all the factor groups are simple; that is, if none of the factor groups of the series contains a normal subgroup. A normal series $\{H_i\}$ of $G$ is a ***principal series*** if all the factor groups are simple.
>
> **Example 8.** The group $\Bbb Z_{60}$ has a composition series $$\Bbb Z_{60}\supset\langle3\rangle\supset\langle15\rangle\supset\langle30\rangle\supset\{0\}$$ with factor groups 
>   $$\begin{array}{rcl}
> \Bbb Z_{60}/\langle3\rangle\!\!\!\! &\cong \!\!\!\!&\Bbb Z_3 \\
> \langle3\rangle/\langle15\rangle\!\!\!\! &\cong \!\!\!\!&\Bbb Z_5 \\
> \langle15\rangle/\langle30\rangle\!\!\!\! &\cong \!\!\!\!&\Bbb Z_2 \\
> \langle30\rangle/\{0\}\!\!\!\! &\cong \!\!\!\!&\Bbb Z_2 \\
> \end{array}$$ Since $\Bbb Z_{60}$ is an abelian group, this series is automatically a principal series. Notice that a composition series need not to be unique. The series $$\Bbb Z_{60}\supset\langle2\rangle\supset\langle4\rangle\supset\langle20\rangle\supset\{0\}$$  is also a composition series. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

How it comes that none of the $\mathbb Z_2$ or $\mathbb Z_3$ or $\mathbb Z_5$ has no normal subgroup?! $\mathbb Z_2$ is normal subgroup of $\mathbb Z_5$.

Comment: "$\mathbb Z_2$ is normal subgroup of $\mathbb Z_5$." Sure that $\mathbb Z_2$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_5$, to begin with?

Comment: $\Bbb Z_2$, $\Bbb Z_3$, $\Bbb Z_5$ each have no proper nontrivial subgroups; $\Bbb Z_p$ for $p$ prime is simple. In particular, $\Bbb Z_2$ is not a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_5$. If you think of the underlying set of $\Bbb Z_n$ as $\{0,\cdots,n-1\}$ then you might get the impression that $\Bbb Z_n$ is a subset of $\Bbb Z_m$ when $n\le m$, but this is a very wrong way of thinking. By the way, cyclic groups are introduced and studied thoroughly way before composition series are in group theory, so something is fishy here. Are you skipping ahead?

Comment: @anon - no I have studied cyclic gps as well. $\mathbb Z_n$ is a subset of $\mathbb Z_m$ when n≤m and groups as well and also same id. So $\mathbb Z_n$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_m$ when n≤m, indeed. Why am I wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Absolutely not. For instance $0=1+1$ in $\Bbb Z_2$ but $0\ne 1+1$ in $\Bbb Z_5$. If you think of the underlying set of $\Bbb Z_n$ as $\{0,\cdots,n-1\}$ then even though $\Bbb Z_n\subset\Bbb Z_m$ when $n<m$, it will *never* be the case that $\Bbb Z_n$'s multiplication table is a subset of $\Bbb Z_m$'s multiplication table, so they'll never be subgroups that way. It's dangerous to even think of one as a subset of the other, I highly recommend you avoid that thinking.

Comment: Indeed it should be absolutely clear to you that $\Bbb Z_2\subset\Bbb Z_5$ is impossible simply by observation and very early group theory concepts. Their sizes $2$ and $5$ fail Lagrange's theorem, for example. $\Bbb Z_2$ has an element of order two but $\Bbb Z_5$ doesn't. This is a major blindspot you need to fix! As Did mentions below, the best definition / construction of $\Bbb Z_n$ is $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, the set of cosets of $n\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Z$, considered as a quotient group. This is technically different from considering $\Bbb Z_n$s elements to be integers between $0$ and $n-1$.

Comment: Anyway we know that elements of the groups $\mathbb Z_n$ are best viewed as *subsets* of $\mathbb Z$ rather than as integers, right? For example $2\mathbb Z\in\mathbb Z_2$ (yes, $\in$, not $\subset$) but $2\mathbb Z\notin\mathbb Z_5$. More generally, $\mathbb Z_n\cap\mathbb Z_k=\varnothing$ for every positive integers $k\ne n$.

Comment: @anon - In fact, I learnt A LOT better by your comments than a long way through the book. It was a revolution in my mind! I truly appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Z}_2$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_5$. All groups of prime order are cyclic and are generated by any nonidentity element. In particular, they are simple.

Answer (score 2):

By Lagrange's Theorem the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group. If you have a subgroup $H < G$, then the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$, hence $\vert H \vert = 1$ or $\vert H \vert = p$ as the order of $G$ is prime. This shows that e.g. $\mathbf{Z}_3$ is simple.